# Recommended way to have drawer resizable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, resize, material-ui

I would like to have the material ui drawer's width resizable through a draggable handle.
My current approach is to have a mousevent listener on the whole app which checks if handle was pressed and updates the width according to mouse position on every mouse move.

This however requires a constant mouseevent listener on the whole app which seems to be overkill for a simple resize feature.

Are there better/ recommended ways of doing the resize?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use indicator dragger with `mousedown` on it.

Here for example

```
// styles
dragger: {
  width: '5px',
  cursor: 'ew-resize',
  padding: '4px 0 0',
  borderTop: '1px solid #ddd',
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  zIndex: '100',
  backgroundColor: '#f4f7f9'
}

...

state = {
  isResizing: false,
  lastDownX: 0,
  newWidth: {}
};

handleMousedown = e => {
  this.setState({ isResizing: true, lastDownX: e.clientX });
};

handleMousemove = e => {
  // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
  if (!this.state.isResizing) {
    return;
  }

  let offsetRight =
    document.body.offsetWidth - (e.clientX - document.body.offsetLeft);
  let minWidth = 50;
  let maxWidth = 600;
  if (offsetRight > minWidth && offsetRight < maxWidth) {
    this.setState({ newWidth: { width: offsetRight } });
  }
};

handleMouseup = e => {
  this.setState({ isResizing: false });
};

componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => this.handleMousemove(e));
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', e => this.handleMouseup(e));
}

...

<Drawer
  variant="permanent"
  open
  anchor={'right'}
  classes={{
    paper: classes.drawerPaper
  }}
  PaperProps={{ style: this.state.newWidth }}
>
  <div
    id="dragger"
    onMouseDown={event => {
      this.handleMousedown(event);
    }}
    className={classes.dragger}
  />
  {drawer}
</Drawer>
```

The idea is, when click the dragger, it will resize width `Drawer` followed mouse move.

Play [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2h1g6x?file=index.js).

Comment: Thanks for this awesome reply! Before accepting this answer, what would you think about only adding the mousemove listener on click of drag handle and unregistering on mouseup?
This would prevent the mousemove event listener to be on 99% of the time.

Comment: @nauti, Do you mean by  `Drawer`? if so, you can do it as long as `Drawer` has handle `mousemove` prop (I have not check it). If not you can put at children of `Drawer`. It depends on you how to implement this, I suggest you to think about `UI/UX` as well. Because mostly user will use it. like mouse will change to dragger icon when hover/click outside link (only link have pointer icon). It depend on your requirement.

Comment: also you can add `document.removeEventListener(...)` to remove listener if you think need it at `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: When I click to resize, the container jumps and is about 10 px left of where my cursor is dragging.

Comment: This is pretty cool! Thanks.

Comment: @hendrathings is there a way that when you resize, the stuff on the left resize with it?(So like you wanted the resizable drawer and other things)

Comment: I looked at the demo and it's really slick.  I don't suppose you know of a way to do the same in pure Angular?  It's "side-nav" component doesn't seem a flexible as the React "drawer".

Comment: Adding +20 here will fix the "jump" => let offsetRight = document.body.offsetWidth - (e.clientX - document.body.offsetLeft) + 20;

Answer (score 10):

It might be a `useResize` hook with API to enable resizing and providing current width.

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

type UseResizeProps = {
  minWidth: number
}

type UseResizeReturn = {
  width: number
  enableResize: () => void
}

const useResize = ({
  minWidth,
}: UseResizeProps): UseResizeReturn => {
  const [isResizing, setIsResizing] = useState(false)
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(minWidth)

  const enableResize = useCallback(() => {
    setIsResizing(true)
  }, [setIsResizing])

  const disableResize = useCallback(() => {
    setIsResizing(false)
  }, [setIsResizing])

  const resize = useCallback(
    (e: MouseEvent) => {
      if (isResizing) {
        const newWidth = e.clientX // You may want to add some offset here from props
        if (newWidth >= minWidth) {
          setWidth(newWidth)
        }
      }
    },
    [minWidth, isResizing, setWidth],
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', resize)
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', disableResize)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', resize)
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', disableResize)
    }
  }, [disableResize, resize])

  return { width, enableResize }
}

export default useResize
```

Then you could decouple resizing logic from your layout component like this:

```js
const Layout = () => {
  const { width, enableResize } = useResize({ minWidth: 200 });

  return (
    <Drawer
      variant="permanent"
      open
      PaperProps={{ style: { width } }}
    >
      {drawer}
      <div
        style={{ 
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '2px',
          top: '0',
          right: '-1px',
          bottom: '0',
          cursor: 'col-resize'
        }}
        onMouseDown={enableResize}
      />
    </Drawer>
)
```

Comment: Great solution :)

Comment: I found it was helpful to add another state `initialX` and set that as `e.clientX` in `enableResize`.  Then in `resize()` `widthChange= e.clientX - initialX;` and `setInitialX(e.clientWidth);` `setWidth(oldWidth => oldWidth + widthChange)`

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add an answer that is more up to date using React Hooks.

You can do it like this, then:

CSS:

```
sidebar-dragger: {
  width: '5px',
  cursor: 'ew-resize',
  padding: '4px 0 0',
  borderTop: '1px solid #ddd',
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  zIndex: '100',
  backgroundColor: '#f4f7f9'
}
```

React (using hooks with refs and states)

```
let isResizing = null;

function ResizeableSidebar (props) {
  const sidebarPanel = React.useRef('sidebarPanel');
  const cbHandleMouseMove = React.useCallback(handleMousemove, []);
  const cbHandleMouseUp = React.useCallback(handleMouseup, []);

  function handleMousedown (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    // we will only add listeners when needed, and remove them afterward
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', cbHandleMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', cbHandleMouseUp);
    isResizing = true;
  };

  function handleMousemove (e) {
    if (!isResizing) {
      return;
    }

    let offsetRight =
      document.body.offsetWidth - (e.clientX - document.body.offsetLeft);
    let minWidth = 50;
    if (offsetRight > minWidth) {
      let curSize = offsetRight - 60;
      // using a ref instead of state will be way faster
      sidebarPanel.current.style.width = curSize + 'px';
    }
  };

  function handleMouseup (e) {
    if (!isResizing) {
      return;
    }
    isResizing = false;
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', cbHandleMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', cbHandleMouseUp);
  };

  return <div className="sidebar-container">
    <div
      className="sidebar-dragger"
      onMouseDown={handleMousedown}
    />
    <div>
      Your stuff goes here
    </div>
  </div>;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work; don't waste your time with it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zddkrx?file=src/Resizable.js

Comment: I fixed it for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-infffy?file=src%2FResizable.js There were some errors in the CSS and the structure. I hope it helps. This is an educational peace of code. Use it to learn and understand the concepts behind how it works :)

Comment: ~~what is actually making the dragger move? and how do you move it if you want to go from the left of the screen to the right?~~ Never mind, pretty dumb question

Answer (score 2):

Just use a [synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events) on your handle element. That way, you can avoid the messiness/performance costs of having a universal event listener. Something like the following:

```
render() {
     return (
       <div onMouseDown={this.yourResizeFunc}>
       </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: so you mean three events for mousedown up and over? The problem is that if I do that on the element to be resized, the mouseover stops being fired when moving out of the div which should be resized. For that reason those three vents need to be registered on the parent which unfortunately is the whole app.

Comment: @nauti couldn't you just do it on the 'whole app' then but check to make sure the mouse is within the div you want to be resized? Either that or use the onMouseDown of the div and onMouseUp of the app?

Comment: @JeremyF yes that is the solution I tried to give in the ticket, but I am looking for a better/ more performant solution which does not require a constant mousemove listener the whole time the user is on the app just for a simple resize of a div.

Comment: Is this component always mounted? If so, I don't think there's a way around having an event listener constantly registered for the mouseDown event. If there are cases where it's unmounted, you could add the event listener in ```componentDidMount``` and remove it in ```componentWillUnmount```. If however, the resizable component is always visible, your going to need a listener of some kind. Besides, if it is in fact always mounted, it's not exactly dragging down the perf of other pages within your app. You can always optimize when the app grows and the component isn't always mounted

Comment: @JohnMcGowan what about adding the mouseover listener at click of the resize drag button and unregistering on mouseup?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with css only, if that fits your need. It's the simplest solution. Look mom, no javascript.

```css
.resizable {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable"></div>
```

[Reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

Comment: Unfortunately because of my drawer is from the rigght you would need a direction rtl which screws up the layout of the content + the resize handle can only be styled very limited.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the material ui drawer