# Implement Slider for resizing windows inside REACT project

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to find some information on how to implement a resize windows REACT component for a project. I posted a picture and would love a resize windows option here, but I can't find a good resource to research how to implement this. I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology. Could you please point me in the direction to research this?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469834/recommended-way-to-have-drawer-resizable) may help you.

Comment: Thank you, this looks great.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-splitter-layout

Ended up using this and the implementation was very easy.