# A resizable `antd` Drawer?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I would like to provide a way to make an `antd` Drawer resizable ?

I read a popular [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469834/recommended-way-to-have-drawer-resizable) specifically for `material-ui/Drawer` but I am looking to do something very similar with `antd`.

Does anyone have a similar `antd` example - or have a better idea how to handle info getting chopped off at side of the drawer.

Answer (score 5):

You can extend the width of `Drawer` by specifying it on the `width` props. If you don't want to extend it but you want the content to be still fit, you can set the width on `bodyStyle` prop and use `overflow: "auto"`:

```
<Drawer
    title="Basic Drawer"
    placement="right"
    closable={false}
    visible={isDrawerVisible}
    bodyStyle={{
      width: 400,
      overflow: "auto"
    }}
    onClose={toggleDrawerVisible}
>
```

I also made a resizable drawer based on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469834/recommended-way-to-have-drawer-resizable) that you provide in **antd** version (react hooks version answer).

**ResizableDrawer.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Drawer } from "antd";

let isResizing = null;

const ResizableDrawer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const [drawerWidth, setDrawerWidth] = useState(undefined);

  const cbHandleMouseMove = React.useCallback(handleMousemove, []);
  const cbHandleMouseUp = React.useCallback(handleMouseup, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDrawerWidth(props.width);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [props.visible]);

  function handleMouseup(e) {
    if (!isResizing) {
      return;
    }
    isResizing = false;
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", cbHandleMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", cbHandleMouseUp);
  }

  function handleMousedown(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    // we will only add listeners when needed, and remove them afterward
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", cbHandleMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", cbHandleMouseUp);
    isResizing = true;
  }

  function handleMousemove(e) {
    let offsetRight =
      document.body.offsetWidth - (e.clientX - document.body.offsetLeft);
    let minWidth = 256;
    let maxWidth = 600;
    if (offsetRight > minWidth && offsetRight < maxWidth) {
      setDrawerWidth(offsetRight);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Drawer {...props} width={drawerWidth}>
      <div className="sidebar-dragger" onMouseDown={handleMousedown} />
      {children}
    </Drawer>
  );
};

export default ResizableDrawer;
```

and to use it:

```
import ResizableDrawer from "./ResizableDrawer";

<ResizableDrawer
    title="Resizable Drawer"
    placement="right"
    closable={false}
    visible={isResizableDrawerVisible}
    onClose={toggleResizableDrawerVisible}
>
    ...
</ResizableDrawer>
```

See working demo here:

[image: Edit]

Answer (score 2):

1. Have two states for tracking the `width` of the drawer and whether or not the drawer is being resized (`isResizing`).
2. Add two event listeners on the global document where it will listen for `mousemove` and `mouseup`. The `mousemove` event will resize the drawer, only if `isResizing` is true. And the `mouseup` event will set `isResizing` to false.
3. Add a div in your drawer that acts as the draggable border for making the drawer resizable. This div will listen for a `mousedown` event, which will set the state of `isResizing` to true.

Here's the code that has been improved upon from the basic drawer demo from antd's website.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Drawer, Button } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [isResizing, setIsResizing] = useState(false);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(256);

  const showDrawer = () => {
    setVisible(true);
  };

  const onClose = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  };

  const onMouseDown = e => {
    setIsResizing(true);
  };

  const onMouseUp = e => {
    setIsResizing(false);
  };

  const onMouseMove = e => {
    if (isResizing) {
      let offsetRight =
        document.body.offsetWidth - (e.clientX - document.body.offsetLeft);
      const minWidth = 50;
      const maxWidth = 600;
      if (offsetRight > minWidth && offsetRight < maxWidth) {
        setWidth(offsetRight);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
    };
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={showDrawer}>
        Open
      </Button>
      <Drawer
        title="Basic Drawer"
        placement="right"
        closable={false}
        onClose={onClose}
        visible={visible}
        width={width}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            width: "5px",
            padding: "4px 0 0",
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            zIndex: 100,
            cursor: "ew-resize",
            backgroundColor: "#f4f7f9"
          }}
          onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
        />
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
      </Drawer>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

And here's the demo of the code:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mt8rv2?file=index.js)