# Auto-resize area to fit screen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-typescript

I want to create a visual layout according to this picture:

[image]

***Code:***

```
<>
          <Grid
              container
              direction="row"
              justifyContent="flex-start"
              alignItems="flex-start"
          >
              <Grid item>

                  <Grid className={classes1.color}
                        container
                        direction="column"
                        justifyContent="flex-start"
                        alignItems="center"
                  >
                      <Grid item>
                          <Box m={2}>
                              item link 1
                          </Box>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                          <Box m={2}>
                              item link 2
                          </Box>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                          <Box m={2}>
                              item link 3
                          </Box>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                          <Box m={2}>
                              item link 4
                          </Box>
                      </Grid>

                  </Grid>

              </Grid>

              <Grid item>

                  <Grid className={classes2.color}
                        container
                        direction="column"
                        justifyContent="space-around"
                        alignItems="center"
                  >
                      <Grid item>
                          <Box m={10}>
                              item 11
                          </Box>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                          <Box m={10}>
                              item 11
                          </Box>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                          <Box m={10}>
                              item 13
                          </Box>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                          <Box m={10}>
                              item 14
                          </Box>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                          <Box m={10}>
                              item 15
                          </Box>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                          <Box m={10}>
                              item 16
                          </Box>
                      </Grid>

                  </Grid>

              </Grid>

              <Grid item>

                  <Grid className={classes3.color}
                        container
                        direction="column"
                        justifyContent="space-around"
                        alignItems="center"
                  >
                      <Grid item>
                          <Box m={15}>
                              item area 1
                          </Box>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                          <Box m={15}>
                              item area 2
                          </Box>
                      </Grid>
                  </Grid>

              </Grid>

          </Grid>
      </>
```

Full code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-lhrv91?file=Hello.tsx

The issues that I can't solve are how I can add vertical scrollbar for the second column(item 1-6).
I also want to autosize item 'area 1' and 'item area 2' to fit the rest of the horizontal area and add vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

for using vertical scrollbar in second column you can separate the parent `<Grid container>` to three Grid and then use `style={{ height: "100%", overflow: "auto" }}` inside middle `<Grid container>`

base on material-ui [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#props) at **"xl"** and **"xs"** props, you can use `xs={12}` in `<Grid item xs={12}>` to fit the rest of the horizontal area

check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-violet-yklku) that look like your code

Comment: I have one additional question: is it possible somehow to resize with mouse the left left and right border with mouse drag for the area with `mediumvioletred` color? Sometimes I would need to expand it.

Comment: For some reason I get multiple errors like `TS2769: No overload matches this call.` for this line `xs={xsGridLeft}`

Comment: I have a small request. Can you show me the same example using typescript, please?

Comment: Material Design’s responsive UI is based on a 12-column grid layout so the minimum width (xs={1}) should be 8.33334 percent of screen. so i think the resizable grid can not be implement ed smoothly but the idea of grabable resizable component are the same. they all use addeventlistener function onmousedown , onmouseup and onmousemove and change component width. may be this link can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469834/recommended-way-to-have-drawer-resizable/49560493#49560493

Comment: Thank you for the response. One small request. Can you show me the same solution into Typescript, please?